# Prepare a range for an ex command without visual mode or line numbers

Tags: cursor-motions, ex-mode

### Background:

I can pipe a paragraph through an external command using `!ip` and the cursor goes to the end of the following prompt:

`:.,.+5!`

If I want to use the built-in sort or center functions I could specify the line numbers manually, but I have relative numbers so I would need to count or use visual mode. So currently I use, for example, `!ip<backspace>sort` or `!2}<backspace>center`. This gives me the flexibility to use any kind of range for the command, and I can run it from anywhere inside the range.

### Question:

Is there a way I could do something similar to `!<range>` but ending up without the `!` at the end of the prompt, that I then need to delete? Something like `<foo>ipsort` to end up with `:.,.+6sort`.

Comment: it is explained in the help: `:h N:`

Comment: That doesn't work in the middle of a paragraph though, whereas `!ip` for example would.

Comment: How about using `vip:sort`?

Comment: That's the closest I've found, I was wondering if there was a way to do this but without the visual select.

Comment: I'm confused, but could a mapping like `nnoremap ps :.,sort<left><left><left><left>` helps you? It gives you a prompt prepared to sort from here (`.` is already set) and you can set the end point for the range.

Answer (score 2):

the vim range command supports relative ranges.
So if you are anywhere in your paragraph and you do not want to use visual mode, you can type i.e.:

`:-1,+2!`

Which would use the line above the current line and the following two lines.

If you would like to know more about ranges `:h range`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this isn't built-in. However, since it `!{motion}` results in the notation `:<range>!` you can just remove the `!` in command-line mode and enter your ex command instead. For the :sort command, it could be done like this `!{motion}<BS>sort` (e.g. `!ip<BS>sort`)

Comment: I think OP does that but is looking for a cleaner solution